# Scrape TripAdvisor Hotel Page with Python

Tags: python, scrape, tripadvisor

I'm currently building a scraper to get reviews and ratings.

Have it working for Restaurants but it gives me a 400 for Hotels

Here's the code: https://gist.github.com/jamieaitken/e6df15db9f1204fe67c16f1404996c6f

Comment: Please show some proof of attempt for the scraping.

Comment: Fun Fact: `request('GET', url=urlNotWork)` did work. So i guess something is wrong with the headers ...

Comment: @yogkm Updated post so that all the code is in a gist

Comment: @meissner_ Could you post that as an answer please? It worked so thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hhm, regular requests should work just fine here, like:

```
from requests import request as req

url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g60745-d121009-Reviews-Holiday_Inn_Express_Boston-Boston_Massachusetts.html'
rsp = req('GET', url)

if rsp.status_code == 200:
    print(rsp.text.encode('utf-8'))
```